# C# Reading Paths From Text File Says Path Doesn't Exist

Tags: c#, command-line, text-files, streamreader

I'm developing a small command line utility to remove files from a directory. The user has the option to specify a path at the command line or have the paths being read from a text file.

Here is a sample text input:

```
C:\Users\MrRobot\Desktop\Delete
C:\Users\MrRobot\Desktop\Erase
C:\Users\MrRobot\Desktop\Test
```

My Code:

```
class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Console.WriteLine("Number of command line parameters = {0}", args.Length);

            if(args[0] == "-tpath:"){

                    clearPath(args[1]);
            }
            else
                if(args[0] == "-treadtxt:"){

                    readFromText(args[1]);
                }

        }

        public static void clearPath(string path)
        {
            if(Directory.Exists(path)){

                int directoryCount = Directory.GetDirectories(path).Length;

                if(directoryCount > 0){

                    DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(path);

                    foreach (DirectoryInfo dir in di.GetDirectories())
                    {
                        dir.Delete(true); 
                    }

                }
                else{

                    Console.WriteLine("No Subdirectories to Remove");
                }

                int fileCount = Directory.GetFiles(path).Length;

                if(fileCount > 0){

                    System.IO.DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(path);

                    foreach (FileInfo file in di.GetFiles())
                    {
                            file.Delete(); 
                    }


                }
                else{

                    Console.WriteLine("No Files to Remove");
                }

                }
            else{

                Console.WriteLine("Path Doesn't Exist {0}", path);
            }
        }

        public static void readFromText(string pathtotext)
        {
                try
                {   // Open the text file using a stream reader.
                    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(pathtotext))
                    {
                        // Read the stream to a string, and write the string to the console.
                        string line = sr.ReadToEnd();
                        clearPath(line);
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("The file could not be read:");
                    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                }

        }

    }
}
```

**My Problem:**

When reading from the text file, it says that the first path doesn't exist, and prints all the paths to the prompt, despite that I have no `Console.WriteLine()`.  However, if I plug these same paths and call -tPath: it will work. My issue seems to be in the `readFromText()` I just can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: Aside from anything else, I strongly recommend that you start following .NET naming conventions.

Answer (score 3):

This is the problem:

```
string line = sr.ReadToEnd();
```

That isn't reading a *line* of data - it's reading the whole file in one go. Your `clearPath` method expects its parameter to be a single path, not a bunch of lines glued together. The reason you're seeing all the paths is that `clearPath` is being called (with everything in one call), that "glued together" path isn't being found, and it's printing out the input in `Console.WriteLine("Path Doesn't Exist {0}", path);`.

I suspect you should use something like:

```
var lines = File.ReadAllLines(pathtotext);
foreach (var line in lines)
{
    clearPath(pathtotext);
}
```